# Classpath when re-implementing Java package?

Tags: java, package

I'm working on creating my own implementation of one of the system Java packages but am having some problems with the wrong class getting picked up when trying to use the package.

For example, lets say my package is: **a.b.c.DoStuff** and there is an existing Java package with the exact same name, **a.b.c.DoStuff**.

Using the following code in a test application, I can tell that the system class is still getting used (located in /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/lib/rt.jar) instead of my own:

```
ClassLoader loader = test.class.getClassLoader();
System.out.println(loader.getResource("a.b.c.DoStuff.class");
```

My package has been compiled into a jar file (**package.jar**), and I have:

1. Imported the class in my test file (import a.b.c.DoStuff;)
2. Added package.jar to my classpath (with both "export CLASSPATH..." and using "java -classpath...")

There must be something I'm overlooking?  Any thoughts on how to get my package picked up instead of the system package?

Thanks,
Chris

Answer (score 2):

You can't replace classes from the standard packages unless you put your jar in the special 'endorsed' directory. And some you can't replace at all that way.

Comment: There are only certain packages you can replace with the endorsed list. Not all.

Comment: Does the bootclasspath let you get everything?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, bmargulies for the tip on the bootclasspath!
  Prepending my .jar file to the bootclasspath solved my problem.  To summarize, I was able to use my own Java package implementation by prepending my package's .jar to the bootclasspath:

```
java -Xbootclasspath/p:<path-to-jar>
```